# Custom page_size with PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, pdfkit

Im using Rails 3.1 and the PDFKit gem..

how can i set a custom page_size? (i dont want to use the default "letter or A4")

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834044/pdfkit-apparently-not-working-because-of-wkhtmltopdf):

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = `which wkhtmltopdf`.to_s.strip
  config.default_options = {
    :encoding=>"UTF-8",
    :page_size=>"A4", #or "Letter" or whatever needed
    :margin_top=>"0.25in",
    :margin_right=>"1in",
    :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
    :margin_left=>"1in",
    :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
    }
end
```

You can change the `:page_size` variable to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `page_width` and `page_height` in your initializer.

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
     :page_width => '169.33',
     :page_height => '95.25'
  }
end
```

Or `page_width` and `page_height` in your code.

```
kit = PDFKit.new(html, page_width: '169.33', page_height: '95.25')
```

The value is in millimeters, thanks to [j.avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1974367/j-avi) for sharing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607267/385730).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
var doc = new PDFDocument({
  size: [240, 320]
});
```