# Rails 3 and PDFKit. How to specify page size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdfkit

I have been looking in the documentation but can't find the answer. How can I specify the page size of my pdf document and what are the available page sizes? I keep on looking and looking but I can't find good documentation. Please point me to a URL or let me know how can I code some page size into my PDF document.

Oh and I don't want to do that on any config file because I need to generate PDf documents of different sizes.

NOT in config file...

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
config.wkhtmltopdf = `which wkhtmltopdf`.to_s.strip
config.default_options = {
  :encoding=>"UTF-8",
  :page_size=>"A4", #or "Letter" or whatever needed
  :margin_top=>"0.25in",
  :margin_right=>"1in",
  :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
  :margin_left=>"1in",
  :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
  }
end
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Did this work for you? If true, accept?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the page size when creating a new PDF like this:

```
kit = PDFKit.new(source, :page_size => "Legal")
```

PDFKit uses WKHTMLTOPDF which in turn uses QPrinter. You can find the available sizes in the [QPrinter documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum) (there's a bunch), but its pretty safe to say that any size paper you want is available. Also, you can set a custom size if you can't find what you need.

NB: If you don't set a default option for `page_size` in a config somewhere AND don't supply one in your method call, PDFKit will use its internal default (Letter). See line 10 of [lib/pdfkit/configuration.rb](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/pdfkit/configuration.rb)

Answer (score 3):

Pdkit accepts custom sizes:

```
  PDFKit.configure do |config|
    config.wkhtmltopdf = `which wkhtmltopdf`.strip
    config.default_options = {
          :page_width => '1682',
          :page_height => '2378'
      }
  end
```

The sizes must be in milimeters (wkthmltopdf documentation).

Comment: Specifying `page_width` and `page_height` in millimeters worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's using wkhtmltopdf to generate the PDFs I'm assuming you can use the same options that it supports. In a wkhtmltopdf manual I found, it mentions the following site for a list of sizes:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum

To set the page size, you can use the :page_size option like so:

```
PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
```

Comment: hi,wer does this line `PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')` go?in the controller or in the view?or in the pdfkit.rb?